# syntax error on current_settings(proc.myvar)::varchar2(1024) postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to create a procedure where I have stored parameter values in postgres.auto.conf file but unable to resolve Syntax error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testproc.test_mans_clr ( in_usercode text, in_usersess text, in_compcode text, out_code INOUT numeric ) AS $body$
BEGIN
      PERFORM test_delete_table(in_usercode, 'sygbmess', in_usersess);
      PERFORM test_delete_table(in_usercode,
                                      'mm_gb_serinf_gtlt',
                                      in_usersess
                                     );
      PERFORM test_delete_table(in_usercode,
                                      'mm_gb_sericale_info',
                                      in_usersess
                                     );
      PERFORM test_delete_table(in_usercode,
                                      'mm_gb_sericale_seri',
                                      in_usersess
                                     );
      PERFORM set_config('testproc.out_code', 0, false);
      COMMIT;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         PERFORM set_config('testproc.out_code', SQLSTATE, false);
         PERFORM set_config('testproc.out_messdesc', INITCAP(trim(both SUBSTR(SQLERRM,
                                   11,
                                     INSTR(INITCAP(trim(both SQLERRM)),
                                            'Ora-',
                                            1,
                                            2
                                           )
                                   - 12
                                  )
                          )
                    ), false);
         test_exception_message(in_usercode,
                                       current_setting('testproc.out_code')::varchar(1024),
                                       current_setting('testproc.out_messdesc')::varchar(1024),
                                       in_usersess
                                      );
   END;


$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
SECURITY DEFINER
;
```

ERROR:

> syntax error at or near "test_exception_message"
>
> LINE 32:          test_exception_message(in_usercode,

where is the actual problem?

Comment: what is `**` ? Maybe it is broken comment?

Comment: Looked like an attempt to bold part of the code before it was formatted as code. Tried to fix things now.